# In pandas appending to existing df, with out changing id of df?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df1` with some text and numbers as columns.
I created the fresh row with data and appended to df1 using pandas as follows. the id of result df is changing. 
Is there a way that the main df1's id is not changed, and appending to existing df, without changing the id of df?

My code is :

```
import cStringIO as io
import pandas as pd

def test():
    text_data = """bcd  11  
    abc  12  
    def  13
    ghi  14"""

    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_data), header=None, sep="\s+", names=["txt", "num"])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([["pqr", 1]], columns=["txt", "num"])
    print "id is =",id(df), "\n" ,df
    df = pd.concat([df, df2])
    print "id is =", id(df), "\n", df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if append only one row and use [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) , but if use `concat` or `append` get new `DataFrame` object (different `id`s):

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO

def test():
    text_data = """bcd  11  
    abc  12  
    def  13
    ghi  14"""

    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text_data), header=None, sep="\s+", names=["txt", "num"])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([["pqr", 1]], columns=["txt", "num"])
    print ("id is =",id(df), "\n" ,df)
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = df2.iloc[0]
    print ("id is =", id(df), "\n", df)

test()

id is = 243587168 
    txt  num
0  bcd   11
1  abc   12
2  def   13
3  ghi   14
id is = 243587168 
    txt  num
0  bcd   11
1  abc   12
2  def   13
3  ghi   14
4  pqr    1
```